# How to expand macro name when passing it to luamplib code to be used as a file name?

Tags: luatex, metapost

I need to pass some string of text from my LuaLaTeX document to be used as a file name. Here's a kind of MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\def\testfilename{test1}
\def\writesomewords#1#2{
    \begin{mplibcode}
        beginfig(0);
        string somewords;
        somewords = "somewords";
        draw textext("#1");
        draw textext("#2") shifted (0, -1cm);
        write somewords to "#1.txt";
        write EOF to "#1.txt";
        write somewords to "#2.txt";
        write EOF to "#2.txt";
        endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
    }
\begin{document}
    \writesomewords{\testfilename}{test2}
\end{document}
```

Most of the time arguments are passed just fine, and both `draw textext("...");` clauses produce the expected result:

[image]

However, when it comes to file names, whereas the second file is named `test2.txt` as expected, the first file ends up called `\testfilename` for some reason (as the original macro, which holds the intended name). Apparently, it doesn't expand in this particular case.

This might be a bug (which is somewhat likely, given that an analogous code works fine in ConTeXt), in which case I'll report it, but it just might be an intended behavior, in which case: how do I expand the file name so it does end up as a file name in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mplibcode` prevents expansion but you can use `\expanded` to expand the arguments first

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\def\testfilename{test1}
\def\writesomewords#1#2{
    \expanded{\noexpand\begin{mplibcode}
        beginfig(0);
        string somewords;
        somewords = "somewords";
        draw textext("#1");
        draw textext("#2") shifted (0, -1cm);
        write somewords to "#1.txt";
        write EOF to "#1.txt";
        write somewords to "#2.txt";
        write EOF to "#2.txt";
        endfig;
    \noexpand\end{mplibcode}}
    }
\begin{document}
    \writesomewords{\testfilename}{test2}
\end{document}
```

produces `test1.txt`

```
somewords
```

and

[image]

Comment: `mplibcode` allows for LaTeX commands in its body, for later processing, which is the reason for suppressing expansion, so doing full expansion of the body might not be the best strategy.

Comment: yes sure, but here that isn't an issue. you could always use `\noexpand` as shown for `\begin`  if a different version required latex commands in the body (or `\unexpanded...}` @egreg

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with an auxiliary macro to which you pass the expanded arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\newcommand{\testfilename}{test1}
\newcommand{\writesomewords}[2]{%
  \ExpandArgs{ee}\writesomewordsaux{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\writesomewordsaux}[2]{%
  \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(0);
    string somewords;
    somewords = "somewords";
    draw textext("#1");
    draw textext("#2") shifted (0, -1cm);
    write somewords to "#1.txt";
    write EOF to "#1.txt";
    write somewords to "#2.txt";
    write EOF to "#2.txt";
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}%
}

\begin{document}

\writesomewords{\testfilename}{test2}

\end{document}
```

If you're running an older LaTeX distribution, replace with

```
\newcommand{\writesomewords}[2]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\writesomewordsaux{#1}{#2}}%
}
```